# Best date picker (calendar) for ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, calendar

I have a `ReactJS` application with a large form. It has many input fields requiring filling dates from a calendar. Now, I need to choose a date picker/ calendar library which supports following date formats:

```
1. only year (e.g. 2012)
2. only month and year (e.g. March 2012)
3. date picker (e.g.2012/03/15)
4. date range picker (e.g. 2012/03/15 - 2013/03/15)
5. date range picker for month and year (e.g. March 2012 - March 2013)
6. frequencies (e.g. daily, weekly, monthly)
```

Can anyone suggest me which package/library is the best date picker considering the above criteria ? you can suggest 5 libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer React DatePicker

`npm i react-datepicker`

[image]

Comment: i tried React DatePicker, but it was difficult to adjust it with a functional component for my form input fields

Comment: is it better than react-day-picker ?

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: React DatePicker does not support frequencies like weekly, Monthly, yearly

Answer (score 0):

You can try MUI date/time picker I have used it before and it's easy to use ,
you can have a look at their demo here
https://codesandbox.io/s/c4u1jf?file=/demo.js

docs : https://mui.com/components/pickers/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can you please explain why is this the best date picker for a ReactJS application ?

Comment: is it better than react-day-picker ?

Comment: @Wael Ben Mustapha please check updated question

Comment: it's a personal preference for me i haven't used react-day-picker but i did try mui date/time picker and i can tell you it's easy to use . just try to use it and see if it fits in your work , i can help you if there in any problem